# Adjusted exponential reduction

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a problem where an amount, lets say $x$, are reduced by some percentage $p$ over a duration of $n$ descrete iterations. I want to calculate a factor $f$ such that $x_i = f_i \cdot x$, and the $n$th factor reduces $x$ to $x_n$ by $p$ percent: $f_n = (1-p)$. This gives a sequence of factors that look much like

$$f_i = (1-p)^{1/(n-i+1)} \quad \forall\,i\in [1,n]$$

My problem is that this yields a massive reduction from $x_{n-1}$ to $x_n$. An example where $p = 0,05$ and $n = 8$ yields the sequence $x_1 = 0.9936, x_2 = 0.9927, x_3 = 0.9915, x_4 = 0.9899, x_5 = 0.9873, x_6 = 0.9830, x_7 = 0.9747, x_8 = 0.9500$, where the jump from $n-1$ to $n$ is (not surprisingly) quite massive.

I've tried a linear approach ($f_i = \frac{p}{n}\cdot i$), but it's too "radical" i.e. there's way too much going on when $i$ is small, and the accumulated change in $x_i$ is to big. See figure below

[image]

Are there alternatives that could soften the dynamics of the sequence, such that some of the reduction when $i$ is close to $n$ are distributed more evenly accross the change? Some alternative between the two plotted examples?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is of course as simple as $\pi$.

$$ f_i = 1 - p\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^q $$

where $0 < q < 1$ yields a concave profile, while $1 < q$ yields a convex profile. $q = 1$ gives the linear relation.

An example with $q = 1/3$, $q = 0.5$, $q = 1.2$, $q = 2$ and $q = 1$ is given below.

[image]